# Use kohana relations (has_many etc..) with kohana-pagination

Tags: php, pagination, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm using the [kohana-pagination module by Morgan](https://github.com/morgan/kohana-paginate) ([guide](http://dev.morgan.ly/kohana/v3.3/index.php/guide/paginate/basics)) and I would like to know how can I use the relation between tables with this one.

Here is an example.

I have three tables `categories`, `posts` and `categories_post` (pivot table)

`Categories` *has_many* `Posts` *through* `categories_post` and `Posts` *has_many* `Categories` *through* `categories_post`

Fine, works perfect with kohana.

Now I would like to use the pagination module to display a list of posts and their categories. Usually I just `JOIN` the tables and then I fetch, but with Kohana + this module I don't know how to use it.

I've tried with this :

```
$paginate = Paginate::factory(ORM::factory('post')))->columns(array('id','categories.name'))->execute();
```

Comment: You need to show some effort in doing this yourself. Why can't follow the guide/where does it not work? And do you want over posts (and then show their categories), categories or both?

Comment: I would like to get a list of posts with their categories in the same.
i'll put an example of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to setup the ORM object prior to initializing Paginate and you should have no issues using relationships. Keep in mind that Paginate is simply building atop your object prior to pulling a response.

If the relationship is being handled in the ORM class, there is nothing special to do with Paginate. Recommend prefixing the column names with the table name ("post.id" for example). If you are joining outside of ORM, be sure to do so prior to passing ORM to Paginate:

```
$post = ORM::factory('post')
    ->join('category')
    ->on('post.id', '=', 'category.post_id');

$paginate = Paginate::factory($post)
    ->columns(array('post.id','category.name'))
    ->execute();
```

I'm the creator and maintainer of Paginate and am happy to answer any questions you might have. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for this perfect module :)
So i just have to use as usually the orm (by puttin the join tables etc..), the paginate sys can't get access directly to the relationships (has_many, has_many_through etc..) (they are already in the ORM object) .. maybe you can automatically join them